# react setstate does not work properly on loops

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, setstate, use-state

i am getting a validation response from my backend as an array like this

```
 [
        { param: "secondName", msg: "second name is required" },
        { param: "password", msg: "password is required" }
 ]
```

and i have a state in my react component like this

```
  const [errs, setErrs] = useState({
    firstName: null,
    secondName: null,
    password: null,
    email: null,
  })
```

goal is to change in my state only the fields mentioned in my `response.params` on form submit and leave out the rest as they are `null`.
this is what i tried:

```
const submitFoo = () => {
    console.log(localErrs) //all props are set to null (default)
    res.forEach((single) => {
        setLocalErrs({
            ...localErrs,
            [single.param]: single.msg
        });
    });
    console.log(localErrs);//only password is set to the `response.msg`, instead of `password` AND `secondName`
};
```

but the issue is it's only changing the last item in my "errs state";
output is:

```
{
    first: null,
    second: null,
    password: 'password is required',
    email: null,
}
```

ps: i tried it with vanilla js by looping through the array and setting Errs obj's props directly to the response.msg and it worked. so proplem must be with react setstate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Fat Arrow approach to set state as follows:

```
setLocalErrs(localErrs => ({ ...localErrs, [single.param]: single.msg }));
```

It avoids state loss in case setter function is called twice at the same time due to different async calls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid updating [state in a loop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). Update state like:

```
let errObj = {}
res.forEach((single) => {
  errObj[single.param] = single.msg
})
setLocalErrs({
  ...localErrs,
  ...errObj
})
```

By the way, you can simply use:

```
setLocalErrs(errObj)
```

Since `errObj` has all updated states value.